# ErrorException Undefined property: stdClass::$contents

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error in laravel, I don't know what to do.

> ErrorException Undefined property: stdClass::$contents

pls let me know what other file should I share?

this is the file MarketplaceRepository.php

Do i need to share any blade file?

```
public function getRareCoins() {

    $item=[];

    $collectionForSale = Group::where('user_id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)->where('sale_status', 2)->paginate(24);

    if($collectionForSale){

        $rareCoins=[];

        foreach ($collectionForSale as $collection) {

            $raida = new raida();

            $collectionData = $raida->getCollection($collection->wallet_name);



            $walletCollections = [];

            if($collectionData && $collectionData->payload && $collectionData->payload->contents) {

                if(count($collectionData->payload->contents)>0) {

                    $collectionType = count($collectionData->payload->contents) == 1 ? 1 : 2;



                    if($collectionType == 1) { //rare coin

                        foreach($collectionData->payload->contents as $cc) {

                            $num = $this->dec2hex($cc);

                            $color = $this->hexToRgb($num);

                            $color = implode(',',$color);



                            $walletCollections = [

                                'id' => $collection->id,

                                'name' => $collection->name,

                                'serial_number' => $cc,

                                'ip' => $this->sn2ip($cc),

                                'color' => $color,
```

Comment: Sounds like `$collectionData->payload` simply doesn't have a `contents` property.

Comment: what to do then @CBroe ?

Comment: You have given us virtually no info what kind of data you are dealing with there, or what you intend to do with it. Maybe you need to see to it that all those data objects _do_ have that property, or maybe it is _optional_ and you just need to write your code to also _treat_ this property as optional then ...

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing indicates that you're trying to access the **contents** property of an object, but that property doesn't exist.

If the **payload** property exists but doesn't contain a **contents** property, then you may need to modify your code to handle this case. For example, you could add a check like this:

```
if (isset($collectionData->payload->contents)) {
    // Your existing code here
} else {
    // Handle the case where $collectionData->payload->contents doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: you dont need to check each step when using `isset()` it is safe to directly check the variable you are aiming at.